# Meteor.js and Bootstrap modal dismiss

Tags: javascript, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal, meteor-accounts

I use a bootstrap modal in my meteor app to display login panel (account-ui package).
After successful login is displayed a button "Go to dashboard" with a router redirect to /dashboard.

```
{{#if currentUser}}

<a href="/dashboard" class="btn btn-primary">Go to dashboard</a>

{{else}}
    {{> register}}
    {{> login}}
{{/if}}
```

The problem is, that after redirection even if modal disappear the screen stays black and and whole page is blocked (exactly like with the modal, just without modal).

If if add data-dismiss="modal" to my redirection button, modal is dismissed but redirection doesn't work - I am still on my home page.

```
<a href="/dashboard" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Go to dashboard</a>
```

How can I make it to dismiss a modal and still redirect me to the router link?

Comment: $('#modal').modal('hide'); Router.go('route_after_dissmiss')

Comment: Should I bind it somehow to the button? It still doesn't work if I use: $('#myModal').modal('hide'); Router.go('/dashboard')

Comment: yes, bind it to the button for an click event. Actually it would be better to use modal event as a callback for router, as such: `$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {Router.go()})`

Comment: When using your code I get an error about Unexpected token. What could be wrong?    ('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {FlowRouter.go('/dashboard')})

Comment: There's the `$` missing in your code @MarekHas - try `$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {FlowRouter.go('/dashboard')})`